# store a high amount of HTML files

Tags: c++, linux, storage, nfs

i'm working on an academic project(a **search engine**), the main functions of this search engine are:

```
    1/-crawling
    2/-storing
    3/-indexing
    4/-page ranking
```

all the sites that my search engine will crawl are available locally which means it's an **intranet search engine**.

after storing the files found by the crawler, these files need to be served quickly for caching purpose.

**so i wonder what is the fastest way to store and retrieve these file ?**

the first idea that came up is to use FTP or SSH, but these protocols are connection based protocols, the time to connect, search for the file and get it is lengthy.

i've already read about google's anatomy, i saw that they use a data repository, i'd like to do the same but i don't know how.

NOTES: i'm using Linux/debian, and the search engine back-end is coded using C/C++. **HELP !**

Comment: Why not a simple database? MySQL for example. You can compress the content if storage capacity is critical and you can afford the computational overhead.

Comment: of course, but in the subject they told us no database permitted to store HTML files :/
is there a second way

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "serving" the files. With FTP/SSH, did you talk about "serving" the pages or how you would fetch them after finding them *in order* to serve them (with something else?) A web page is best served via HTTP, isn't that an option? If you have to write an own server application for that, try to find an HTTP server implementation as a library, or if you're not allowed to use one, write a very simple one yourself. Then, simply provide your cached files which you crawled onto the hard drive.

Comment: okey, but when the crawler needs a document(HTML file), do i need to serve it via HTTP, it will be cool if the crawler can access the file directrly without downloading the page?

Comment: Now you sound like your crawler crawls from your own application. That's really confusing. I understood it like that: I thought you want to cache web content. Your crawler crawls some other web pages and stores it as a file. You write some application which serves these ("cached") files somehow. Searching happens on the cached files (with some index for speed-up).

Comment: i'm sorry if my english is bad, to simplify i have 2 machines a crawler and a file server, the crawler will check the file server and foreach documents it founds, it will retrieve HTML tags...
i wonder what's the fastest way to access these documents, if possible without even downloading them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store HTML files in a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201659/how-to-store-html-files-in-a-server)

Comment: @KevinPanko i wrote this posts too and no one replied so i decided to write a more detailled topic, HAH! playing the good mods ...

Comment: You should edit a question instead of creating multiple copies of it.

Comment: :o, am sorry but no one seems to care about it. i will delete the last two posts

Comment: so upvote now please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing individual files is quite easy - `wget -r http://www.example.com` will store a local copy of example.com's entire (crawlable) content.

Of course, beware of generated pages, where the content is different depending on when (or from where) you access the page.

Another thing to consider is that maybe you don't really want to store all the pages yourself, but just forward to the site that actually contains the pages - that way, you only need to store a reference to what page contains what words, not the entire page. Since a lot of pages will have much repeated content, you only really need to store the unique words in your database and a list of pages that contain that word (if you also filter out words that occur on nearly every page, such as "if", "and", "it", "to", "do", etc, you can reduce the amount of data that you need to store. Do a count of the number of each word on each page, and then see compare different pages, to find the pages that are meaningless to search.

Comment: ty for your answer, the problem with your solution is that the crawler also have to access these files, they are stored in a remote server(not the same machine), and need to be available quickly like they are in the same machine(without downloading).
BTW, is NFS a good solution for this situation ?

Comment: Why? What exactly are you trying to solve? Once you have read a page to get it's content, you shouldn't need to store it (google does store pages, but that's mostly to not have to rebuild the content when pages are the same one day to the next, as well as being able to show a cache). NFS, HTTP or SSH, they are all pretty much directly dependent on the speed of the network - everything else is close to "no difference".

Comment: it's for caching purpose.

Comment: guys, i read about google's anatomy and i saw that they're using a data repository, do you have any informations about this subject  ?

Comment: Googles data repository is thousands of pretty ordinary PC's in long rows, with plenty of memory. Machines are partitioned based on some sort of sorting criteria, so individual machines are responsible for an separate part of the alphabet - at least as far as I understand. Assuming you are not REALLY thinking of setting this up to compete with google, I would just store the files on the local disk (assuming you really NEED to store them at all - I'm not convinced about that, since sending out a page that redirects to the ORIGINAL page is much easier, and reduces the load on your system).

Comment: Continuing: If you have enough memory, all frequently used files will be loaded into ram, so you won't need to use the local disk much once the file-cache has loaded them the first time.

Comment: thanks mats, i see that you have a good knowledge about google's anatomy, one last question, if a page changed, how google detect the changes so that the crawler REcrawl this page

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect they compare "todays page" with "previous days page". If it's changed, recrawl. (You can of course filter out things that aren't links before you do that!)

Comment: thanks dude , both answers will help still don't have 15 reputations to vote up :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the program is to be constantly running during operation, you could just store the pages in RAM - grab a gigabyte of RAM and you'd be able to store a great many pages. This would be much faster than caching them to the hard disk.

I gather from the question that the user is on a different machine from the search engine, and therefore cache. Perhaps I am overlooking something obvious here, but couldn't you just sent them the HTML over the connection already established between the user and the search engine? Text is very light data-wise, after all, so it shouldn't be too much of a strain on the connection.

Comment: i don't know exactly the size of the pages, it can be more than 2Millions pages(2GIG ram).and after every reboot i need to reload the data in the RAM :/